# Why is MsMpEng.exe using 100% Disk I/O for minutes to scan one small file?

Tags: windows, hard-drive, anti-virus

Occasionally (maybe once a day), when I download any file with my browser and first try to open the download, my Windows 8 box CPU spikes to 100% for a minute or more.  The file doesn't open until this spike subsides.  (Not to mention that I can't do anything else which accesses the disk until it finishes.)

In looking at the Performance Monitor, I see that the process consuming disk is MsMpEng.exe, which as I understand it is Windows Defender.

I see that it is accessing a whole bunch of "Package" files in a Windows\System32\catroot directory.

[image]

Does anyone know what it's doing here, and whether I can prevent and/or optimize it so I don't get these lengthy disk-blocking operations?  My naive guess is that it's loading its dictionary of malware detection/correction definitions from disk into memory but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0):

Windows Defender, Windows' built-in antivirus. You can disable it from its settings.

Comment: To clarify - I don't want to disable virus protection.  I still want the virus protection enabled.  I'm just wondering why the virus check takes so many resources, when for example the file to be scanned might simply be a one-line text file.